# how to write sql query without alias

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to write this sql query without alias? I am using a PHP script that doesn't covers alias so I have problem with that.

If this is possible please provide me with some help

This is the code:

```
SELECT 
 time1.Time, time2.Time, time1.Signal, v.name, v.lastname, k.vehicle, time1.Reg
FROM
 data time1
 INNER JOIN data time2
    ON  time1.id != time2.id 
    AND time1.serial= time2.serial
 INNER JOIN drivers v
    ON time1.FK_ID_driver=v.ID_driver
 INNER JOIN vehicles k
    ON time1.Reg=k.Reg

WHERE
   TIMEDIFF(time2.Time, time1.Time) BETWEEN '00:15:00' AND '00:30:00';
```

Comment: "doesn't cover alias"?  As in you can't specify which column you'd like to get back?  Yow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't easily achieve what you want, since you are joining the same table twice, and SQL needs an alias to disambiguate them.

You could, however, create a view for table `data`, and use the view instead of the table name in one of the `data` joins.

**Example:**

```
select data.time,
    vData.time,
    data.Signal,
    drivers.name,
    drivers.lastname,
    vehicles.vehicle,
    data.Reg
from data 
inner join vData on data.id != vData.id and data.serial = vData.serial
inner join drivers on data.FK_ID_driver = drivers.ID_driver
inner join vehicles on data.Reg = vehicles.Reg
where TIMEDIFF(vData.time, data.time) between '00:15:00' and '00:30:00';
```

Comment: can you give me the example? I will always forward different values in the query

Comment: so how to create view? or this is whole example? I'm sorry but I haven't done views yet

Comment: @denonth See the docs: [CREATE VIEW Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html)